# SSRS 2008 Preview Efficiency

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to report writing and building so I do a lot of back and forth between the preview and the designer to see how the output is progressing.  For the reports with multiple parameters I'm finding it very time consuming to re-enter the parameters for each viewing.  Is there a way that I can choose to keep the parameter selections from the previous preview so I can skip that step? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are deriving your parameters, could be a list of values or could be from a query for example. I am also assuming you are using a report server and therefore developing .rdl reports. NB .rdl reports can also be used as client side reports (.rdlc) by simply providing the data for each dataset in the form of a table

Have you tried setting a default value for each parameter? This can be done via each parameters properties. I don't know of a way to automatically set the default parameter values from the currently selected values.

The reports should then run without you having to enter any values.

Comment: Setting defaults is probably my best bet in this case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parameters "Hidden" by doing following steps :
1. double click Parameters
2. select Hidden radio

Each time you update your SSRS report deploy by doing: 
1. right click on report
2. click on deploy

then copy the url from your ReportServer like:
"ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSSRS_Reports%2fBestCustomers&rs:Command=Render "

After Command=Render type your parameters once as like as follows: 
"servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSSRS_Reports%2fBestCustomers&rs:Command=Render&OrderTrackDate1=param1&OrderTrackDate2=param2"

for example if I replace param1 and param2 with 3/1/2015 and 4/1/2015 I will get my desired report
in my report OrderTrackDate1 and OrderTrackDate2 are report parameters

Each time you update your report then just deploy and reload your browser.

Regards,
Jahangir Alam
BUET 
Dhaka, Bangladesh